# Codeigniter loading two different data array from a database with the second one is dependent with the first one and load into a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my code:

my model : **My_model**

```
function load_modules(){

$modules = $this->db->query('SELECT name FROM module');
$result = $modules->result_array();

return $result;

}

function load_lesson($modname){

$lessons = $this->db->query(
'SELECT lesson.name 
FROM lesson 
INNER JOIN module 
ON module.id = lesson.moduleid and module.name = $modname'
); 

$result = $lessons->result_array();

return $result;

}
```

my controller : **My_controller**

```
$this->load->model('My_model');
$arraydata['values'] = $this->My_model->load_modules();
```

and in my view:

```
foreach($values as $modulename){

load_lesson($modulename); // This is the method from my model which
// I want to be access in my controller in a way that will work like this.

}
```

What I wanted to happen is to be able to get all lessons for each module. But I can't figure out of a way to do it in a controller. Hope you can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: i'm trying to analyze your problem maybe it can be solved on optimizing your query, you selected a name from a table then used it as a reference to another table and joined by the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't try to call a method of a model from a view. try something like this in controller....

```
$this->load->model('My_model');
$arraydata['values'] = $this->My_model->load_modules();
foreach($arraydata['values'] as $key=>$value){
  $arraydata['values'][$key]['lessons']=$this->My_model->load_lesson($value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but how can I load it to a view? How would I display the modules then the lessons for each module? Sorry, but I'm just finding it hard to figure out.

Comment: you can get all lessons in your view like this approach
foreach($values as $modulename){
foreach($modulename['lessons'] as $MYlessions){ echo $MYlessions; }
}
try print_r($values) to view the structure of the array.